# How to setup ExtJS? docs are confusing

Tags: extjs

I need a simple `<script type="text/javascript" src="...">` to show what JS files I need to have in my HTML page to put ExtJS 6 to run.

I try to read this: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html but its a bit confusing... Do I really need to `Download and Install Sencha Cmd 6`? I think I don't need `A "universal" application` ...

This tutorial is a little old http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/02/extjs-tree-json-servlet-mysql.html and I can't find files like `extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css` in the `ext-6.2.0` folder I've downloaded...

This other tutorial starts the code just from the JS ... http://atechiediary.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/extjs-how-to-create-static-and-dynamic.html and don't show the HTML part...

I've downloaded from here: https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/

Comment: I highly recommend using Sencha Cmd, it's small utility and it will generate and basic app from which you can start. And it provides many other features which can significantly help you develop the App. The basic command would look like this: `sencha -sdk 'path/to/downloaded/ext' generate app  --classic MyApp ./myappfolder`

Comment: Sencha Cmd is the recommended way like pagep is suggesting above. But if you are still interested, see thread on sencha forum: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303145-How-can-I-create-new-Extjs-6-application-without-sencha-cmd

Comment: I feel too many authors force their users to use their recommended way to setup the environment, but for many this is not an option. 
Same thing goes with many authors forcing users to use NPM. 
I get that it's beautiful and convenient, but in cases where I just need a simple html file with a simple implementation of that component deployed on a server where I have very limited access (just copy & paste files), I need to do it the basic clean, old fashioned way of just including files and instantiating them!
Too many developers don't bother documenting this method anymore and it's annoying!

Answer (score 2):

Solved : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303990-Is-there-a-free-GPA-CDN-for-ExtJS-6-l&p=1115697&viewfull=1#post1115697

Just follow the `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/` part of the links into the downloaded `ext-6.2.0/build` folder and find all matches.

So `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all-debug.css` becomes `/ext-6.2.0/build/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all-debug.css`.

I think all I need is in the `build` folder.